# VBA range select error (deleting a row)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to implement a `VBA` routine which deletes automatically anything in column I&J which has the word 'delete' in it because this is a validation return which I have set up. I have the following code, yet my code breaks on the second loop whereby I get a subscript out of range. Haven't been able to fix it so if someone could give advice, would be much appreciated.

```
Sub RemoveNA()
'THIS DELETES ALL ROWS WHERE THE VALUE IN COLUMN I IS "DELETE"
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set FoundCell = Range("I:I").Find(what:="DELETE", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Set FoundCell = Range("I:I").FindNext
    Loop

    'THIS DELETES ALL ROWS WHERE THE VALUE IN COLUMN J IS "DELETE"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set FoundCell = Range("J:J").Find(what:="DELETE", LookIn:=xlValue)
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Set FoundCell = Range("J:J").FindNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` twice. Just use it once in the beginning and set it to `True` at the end. Second, just change `FoundCell` to check `Range("I:J")`. Two loops are unnecessary when you can do it with one. Third, missing `s` in `LookIn:=xlValues` in second loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the 's' in 'LookIn:=xlValue' in the second loop.